# How to build P3P headers in Python/Flask?

Tags: python, facebook, flask, jinja2, facebook-iframe

I came across the same problem as this with Safari rejecting the cookies and keep reloading the facebook iframe:

[facebook app iframe login issue on safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828046/facebook-app-iframe-login-issue-on-safari)

The solution in PHP should be something like this:

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="CURa ADMa DEVa PSAo PSDo OUR BUS UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"')
?>
```

I don't really understand PHP, how do I achieve this in Python/Flask? Do I have somehow to set this in every function in the view code or in `base.html`, which all other templates derive from?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [flask.make_response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.make_response)

"Sometimes it is necessary to set additional headers in a view. Because views do not have to return response objects but can return a value that is converted into a response object by Flask itself, it becomes tricky to add headers to it. This function can be called instead of using a return and you will get a response object which you can use to attach headers.

```
def index():
    response = make_response(render_template('index.html', foo=bar))
    # add your P3P header to the response
    response.headers['P3P] = 'xxxx'
    return response
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer. While your solution works, it seems the P3P header solution is no longer a solution to the safari iframe problem. This answers my question but my search has to continue.

Comment: Just a followup question, how is this P3P code generated to solve the cross site cookie problem? I noticed this code is not always the same. Thanks