# How to get access to the cookies in Chrome via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I have two opened tabs in my `Chrome` browser. I want to modify cookies using JavaScript. Is it possible to get access via JS (on the second page) to the cookies from the first page? I'm not sure if I can do such thing.

Actually my question is about almightiness of JavaScript :) and how it really could manage browser data.

Comment: Are the pages hosted on the same domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8433866/4028085

Comment: The following link is related to IE, not Chrome. In Chrome I have one window and multiple tabs. Are you sure it behaves as IE?

Comment: And what if I use the same domain? Is there is some difference?

Comment: browsers by design don't let you access cookies from one domain on another for security reasons...For example if I have a website and try to access your websites cookie that wouldn't be good...