# Cookie issues with iframe

Tags: iframe, cookies, session-variables

We have a website: http://www.soulhair.eu/booking/ and for some reason the online booking form isn't working. We have contacted the people that made the form but they are saying its a cookie issue with the website...

The form is working from time to time on a pc but hardly ever works on a mac, does anybody know if it is a cookie issue or if its a problem with their software. We embedded the system into our site using an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with Safari not accepting cookies from third party sites (so annoying) it wont set cookies inside an iframe unless the customer has first visited the site.

There are heaps of posts and other questions similar to this
[Cross-domain cookies in iframe Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950541/cross-domain-cookies-in-iframe-safari)

AFAIK there isn't really a nice solution to the problem, other than getting the customer to visit the third party site first.  So redirect to a page in the third party site which redirects back to your site.

sux.