# How to auto-size an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, autosize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

I'm loading an iFrame and want the parent to automatically change the height based upon the height of the iFrame's content.

To simply things, all pages belong to the same domain, so I shouldn't run into cross-site scripting issues.

Comment: here is the best solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-100-height

Comment: A more up to date answer, that gives a range of options - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334154/iframe-auto-adjust-height-as-content-changes

Comment: Not a duplicate because cross-site scripting is not an issue here and is in the other post.

Answer (score 37):

On any other element, I would use the `scrollHeight` of the DOM object and set the height accordingly. I don't know if this would work on an iframe (because they're a bit kooky about everything) but it's certainly worth a try.

Edit: Having had a look around, the popular consensus is setting the height from within the iframe using the `offsetHeight`:

```
function setHeight() {
    parent.document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').style.height = document['body'].offsetHeight + 'px';
}
```

And attach that to run with the iframe-body's `onLoad` event.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Just to be clear, should setHeight() be defined WITHIN THE IFRAME HTML? But the-iframe-id is the id of the iframe as defined within the main page html?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't quite work in IE either... it just sizes to the browser height.

Comment: Adding an offset of +- 60 pixels isn't a bad idea to make sure a scrollbar isn't visible (different browsers).

Comment: There is an error in the above code. `parent.document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').height` should be `parent.document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').style.height` instead. Note that `height` is a property of `style` property.

Comment: @SusamPal: With style.height we must specify it's pixels. It should be:

`parent.document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').style.height = document['body'].offsetHeight + 'px';`

Comment: This solution is not working, or maybe it is missing some important information.

Comment: Tested on Firefox, Chrome, Opera its working !!! +1

Comment: When exactly should this code be run? If this is run before the images in the frame are loaded, then it obviously wouldn't be of the correct size once those images load. If we wait for all images to load, then it could take very long if there are pixel tracking images present inside the iframe.

Answer (score 14):

Try:

- [jquery-iframe-auto-height](https://github.com/house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height)
- [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)

Comment: Anyone can tell me how to remove the awful double refresh effect of this plugin? 
e.g.: [sample](http://arthub.hyperborea.com/arthub-container/patrimonio/foto)

Comment: This plugin seems to be working perfectly now

Comment: i was hoping when iframe.height = iframe.scrollHeight didn't work that there'd be a complicated plug-in instead

Comment: More update solution that also works cross domain is: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: Damn, another plugin to do something simple...

Answer (score 11):

I just happened to come by your question and i have a solution. But its in jquery. Its too simple.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css({"min-height": "100", "overflow" : "hidden"});
setInterval( "$('iframe').height($('iframe').contents().find('body').height() + 20)", 1 );
```

There you go!

Cheers! :)

**Edit:** If you have a Rich Text Editor based on the iframe method and not the div method and want it to expand every new line then this code will do the needful.

Comment: Nice, but does not work if there multiple iframes. See my solution ;-)

Comment: I used this code and onload it keeps on expanding the iframe...

Comment: You really shouldn't use eval'd code as first argument of your `setInterval` function. Instead use a callback.

Comment: Does anyone know why the iframe keeps expanding the frame in some pages, but not all? And how can this be prevented?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a dead simple solution that works on every browser and with cross domains:

First, this works on the concept that if the html page containing the iframe is set to a height of 100% and the iframe is styled using css to have a height of 100%, then css will automatically size everything to fit.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
html {height:100%}
body {
margin:0;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe allowtransparency=true frameborder=0 id=rf sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts" scrolling=auto src="http://www.externaldomain.com/" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Does that also work when the iframe is not a direct child of the body but, say, a div (on all browsers, that is)?

Comment: Yes it does - just set the div's height and width using css and then put the iframe inside your div and voila there should only be one set of scrollbars (unless you set the div to be 100% of the height of the page).

Comment: nope, does not. FF 3.6 win xp

Comment: nope, not working in chrome either.

Comment: Looks like this answer from 2010 (!) is no longer correct.

Answer (score 2):

This [solution](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing) worked best for me.  It uses jQuery and the iframe's ".load" event.

Answer (score 1):

In IE 5.5+, you can use the contentWindow property:

```
iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.scrollHeight;
```

In Netscape 6 (assuming firefox as well), contentDocument property:

```
iframe.height = iframe.contentDocument.scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by @ShripadK most helpful, but it does not
work, if there is more than one iframe. My fix is:

```
function autoResizeIFrame() {
  $('iframe').height(
    function() {
      return $(this).contents().find('body').height() + 20;
    }
  )
}

$('iframe').contents().find('body').css(
  {"min-height": "100", "overflow" : "hidden"});

setTimeout(autoResizeIFrame, 2000);
setTimeout(autoResizeIFrame, 10000);
```

- `$('iframe').height($('iframe').contents().find('body').height() + 20)` would set
  the height of every frame to the same value, namely the height of the content of the first frame.
  So I am using jquery's `height()` with a function instead of a value. That way the individual
  heights are calculated
- `+ 20` is a hack to work around iframe scrollbar problems. The number must be bigger than the size of a scrollbar. The hack can probably 
  be avoided but disabling the scrollbars for the iframe.
- I use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval(..., 1)` to reduce CPU load in my case

Answer (score 1):

My solution, (using jquery):

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" class="tabFrame" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" src="http://samedomain" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('.tabFrame').load(function () {
            var iframeContentWindow = this.contentWindow;
            var height = iframeContentWindow.$(document).height();
            this.style.height = height + 'px';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: After small fix works for me: 
$('iframe').load(function() {
    var iframeContentWindow = this.contentWindow;
    var height = $(iframeContentWindow.document).height();
    this.style.height = height + 'px';
});

Comment: and a missing  });  at the end also ;)

Answer (score 0):

Oli has a solution that will work for me. For the record, the page inside my iFrame is rendered by javascript, so I'll need an infinitesimal delay before reporting back the offsetHeight. It looks like something along these lines:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(setHeight);
    });

    function setHeight() {
        alert(document['body'].offsetHeight);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to set the iframe the height/width well over any anticipated source page size in CSS & the `background` property to `transparent`.

In the iframe set `allow-transparency` to `true` and `scrolling` to `no`.

The only thing visible will be whatever source file you use. It works in IE8, Firefox 3, & Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest method i have found using prototype:

Main.html:

```
<html>
<head>


<script src="prototype.js"></script>

<script>
    function init() {
        var iframe = $(document.getElementById("iframe"));
        var iframe_content = $(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("iframe_content"));
        var cy = iframe_content.getDimensions().height;
        iframe.style.height = cy + "px";
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">


<iframe src="./content.html" id="iframe" frameBorder="0" scroll="no"></iframe>

<br>
this is the next line

</body>
</html>
```

content.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>


<style>
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>


<div id="iframe_content" style="max-height:200px;">
Sub content<br>
Sub content<br>
...
...
...
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This seems to work (so far) in all the major browsers.

Comment: Misunderstood the question, fair enough. The code above will resize an iframe to its own content size though (may also be of use to someone)

Answer (score -1):

Actually - Patrick's code sort of worked for me as well. The correct way to do it would be along the lines of this:

Note: there's a bit of jquery ahead:

```
if ($.browser.msie == false) {
    var h = (document.getElementById("iframeID").contentDocument.body.offsetHeight);
} else {
    var h = (document.getElementById("iframeID").Document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: Where's Patricks answer?

Comment: Why not swap the two and get rid of the `== false`? If not, you should just put a `!` at the start instead (`if (!$.browser.msie) {`).