# iframe dynamic height width change based on inner content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have iframe with content like below,

```
    <iframe  frameborder="no" src="http:localhost/com" id="iframe">
     <div style="height:850px;width:700px;">div text </div>
   </iframe>
```

This shows the iframe with hori. and vertical scroll but not the height on inner content of 850px.

how can i change the iframe height dynamiclly based on inner content height n width. Im using jquery inside the content.

**Its cross domain js widget so most of the below answers throwing permission denied error**

Thanxs,
Nithish

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to auto-size an iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247128/how-to-auto-size-an-iframe) Also, check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content).

Comment: One cross-domain solution is described in my second link. But imho, it's better to get rid of iframe and switch to script tag.

Answer (score 2):

Nithish,

if you are using jquery, then you can easily find (and set) the height of any div (in your domain - not on external content) as such:

```
// get the height - in case we want to factor it into the equation below!!
var myDivHeight = $('iframe').css('height');

// set the height
var docHeight = $(document).css('height');
$('iframe').css('height', docHeight);
```

hope this helps ...

Comment: Hi its javascript widget inside that im loading an iframe we can place tht widget anywhere

Comment: well, as long as you have the id of the main containing div of the 'widget', the logic still remains with a minor change. i.e. use $('#idWidgetcontainer').css('height', docHeight); instead.

Comment: ok, is this widget definately from inside your own domain?? (see my little bit above [(in your domain - not on external content)]. it's not possible to get metrics on externally generated content.

Answer (score 2):

```
var newHeight = $("iframe[id='iframeAutenticador']").contents().find("html").height();
$("iframe[id='iframeAutenticador']").height(newHeight);
```

use this.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function to measure the height of the content, and set the IFrame height and then call the resize function when the content is loaded.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function resizeIframeToFitContent(iframe) {
    // This function resizes an IFrame object
    // to fit its content.
    // The IFrame tag must have a unique ID attribute.
    iframe.height = document.frames[iframe.id]
                    .document.body.scrollHeight;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Do NOT use the `language` attribute anymore. It's deprecated. Btw., you should rather use lowercase markup style.

Comment: Actually you should use this, provided you're targeting lower versions of IE. This was the only thing that gave me the correct scroll height in IE 8>

Answer (score 0):

If domains are the same for both pages:

```
parent.document.getElementById("iframe").style.height = $(document).height()+"px";
```

You can use jQuery in parent page too (if its available there).

Comment: Hi its javascript widget inside that im loading an iframe we can place tht widget anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I found this here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

and expanded upon it to re-size width also...you just add this in your head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDocHeight(doc) {
            doc = doc || document;
            // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
            var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
            var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
            return height;
        }
        function getDocWidth(doc) {
            doc = doc || document;
            // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
            var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
            var width = Math.max( body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth,
                html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth );
            return width;
        }
        function setIframeSize(id) {
            var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
            var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: 
                ifrm.contentWindow.document;
            ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
            ifrm.style.width = "10px"; // reset to minimal width ...
            // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
            ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
            ifrm.style.width = getDocWidth( doc ) + 4 + "px";
            ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    </script>
```

Then make sure you have a unique id in your iframe and call the SetIframeSize:

```
<iframe src="source.html" id="uniqueid" onload="setIframeSize(this.id)"></iframe>
```