# Change parameters in iframe src attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, parameters, attributes, src

Searched a lot but didn't find exactly what i'm looking for.
I want to resize an iframe dynamically with width of his container.

HTML :

```
<div class="row hidden" id="audio">
            <div class="twelvecol last">
            <iframe id="deezer" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" src="http://www.deezer.com/fr/plugins/player?autoplay=false&playlist=true&width=710&height=308&scover=true&type=album&id=42808&title=" width="710" height="308"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thx to jQuery i try to inject width and height of div#content into parameters of the iframe's src attribute :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var contentwidth = $('#content').width();
        var contentheight = $('#content').height(); 
        var iframeUrl = 'http://www.deezer.com/fr/plugins/player?autoplay=false&playlist=true&width=' + contentwidth + '&height=' + contentheight + '&scover=true&type=album&id=42808&title=';
        $('#deezer').attr('src', iframeUrl).attr('width', contentwidth).attr('height', contentheight);   
});
</script>
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: What's the problem with the code in your question?

Comment: this code does not affects the width of the iframe. still 710px

Comment: Try [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width) and [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height).

Comment: check the contentwidth and contentheight are getting right value

Comment: thx amilia this are getting right values because i use them to adapt width of facebook like box ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solutions

1. [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)
2. [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)
3. [iframe dynamic height width change based on inner content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913167/iframe-dynamic-height-width-change-based-on-inner-content)
4. [How to auto-size an iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247128/how-to-auto-size-an-iframe)

Comment: thx but it's not enough to change width and height attributes in my case. i also have to modify width and height parameters within src attribute

Comment: Couldnt you just read the height/width of the iframe, and then reuse it?

Comment: @divstudio Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/DYxbf/   I make a sample test.