# How to rewrite this javascript function with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, getelementsbyclassname

```
function setHeight() {
    var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByClassName('targetIframe');
    for(var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++)
    iframes[i].height = document['body'].offsetHeight;
}
```

A variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247128/how-to-auto-size-an-iframe/247160#247160).

It's using the `getElementsByClassName` function,which is not supported by IE.

How to rewrite it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this using [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
function setHeight() {
  $('.targetIframe', parent.document).height(document.body.offsetHeight);
}
```

Or for the literal `height` attribute setting:

```
function setHeight() {
  $('.targetIframe', parent.document).attr('height', document.body.offsetHeight);
}
```

Comment: How to select only the currently onloaded iframe itself?I tried `$(this, parent.document)`,but that's not working .

Comment: @ollydbg - I'm pretty sure you can't, unless the `<iframe>` you're dealing with has a specific ID (or anything else you could identify), is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

```
function setHeight() {
    var $iframes = $(parent.document).find('.targetIframe');

    $iframes.each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).height($(document.body).innerHeight());
    });
}
```

Comment: While this would work, there's a lot of extra jQuery object creation here :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace first line with this:

```
var iframe = $('.targetIframe');
```