# Facebook Iframe Applications Iframe Autoresize Issue?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I have a problem regarding Facebook Iframe Applications Iframe Autoresize. My Form for has a height is greater than the height of default iframe I have tried a lot tricks from Facebook provided functions for **setsize**  and many other through Google. But it does not work.
Can Some one help me who how can I resize my iframe based application to autoresize in height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247128/how-to-auto-size-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Check this FB link: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/93