# Variable height in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, height

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to auto-size an iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247128/how-to-auto-size-an-iframe)

Here is the thing, i have a menu with lots of links, these links have an iframe as target.

The pages that load in the iframe have multiple heights, so i wanted to get the height of the page loaded in the iframe and apply it to the iframe.

I tried some codes with jquery and pure javascript around the net but none worked.

What should i do?

Comment: Is the page in the iframe in a different domain?

Comment: It's in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

If page is on same domain then you can calculate height of document of iframe and based on height you can set height of iframe.

```
$("iframe").load(
          function(){
          $(this).height($(this).contents().height() );
          }
       );
```

Comment: It's on the same domain, but how i can get the heigth of the page loaded on the iframe to change automat the height of the iframe?

I need every page loaded inside the iframe adjusted with it's content

Comment: @user1806962 See my answer . it will automatically set the height on page load

Comment: Thank you @Sushil , i made a mistake in the first try, but now it's working fine. I got confused by all the codes i've tried so far, but now you really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: You should share your your solution here so that other can get help from that.