# PHP - get initial size of a cross-domain iframe page?

Tags: php, iframe, cross-domain

I'm wondering if there is any way with PHP to detect the dimensions of a cross-domain Web page that you have no control over, so as to (initially) set an iframe in your own site to the right size to display it without scrollbars.

In this question:

[Get height of iframe with external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058217/get-height-of-iframe-with-external-url/4087397#4087397)

The poster states "I can get the height of the first page loaded into the iframe (using PHP), but no way of getting subsequent page heights because no way of knowing what the url/location changes to in the iframe."

Does anyone know if that is really possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4058217/445073), the poster states:

> I can get the height of the first page loaded into the iframe (using PHP), but no way of getting subsequent page heights because no way of knowing what the url/location changes to in the iframe

Reading between the lines, that first page loaded into the iframe must be on the same domain, or possibly a different domain but (crucially) under the control of the same developer as the containing page. It's not possible to read the size of the rendered page using PHP - JavaScript is needed client side to obtain the dimensions of what the browser actually renders which is outside the control of any server-side code. So I'm not sure what was meant by "using PHP".

I'm afraid [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058217/get-height-of-iframe-with-external-url/4087397#4087397) still holds: It is **not possible** to get the dimensions of a cross-domain web page that you have no control over, because of the browser's security model. If it *was* possible, that would be a security problem and would have to be fixed. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058217/get-height-of-iframe-with-external-url/4087397#4087397).