# How to open a Link in an Iframe already having its source tag pointing to another page?

Tags: xhtml

I want a link to open in an Iframe which already has its source tag linked to another page. The link and iframe are on same page. Here is the code:

```
<div>
<iframe src="itihaas1.php" id="wrapper" height="1000" width="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>

    </div>
<div><a href="itihaas2.php" target="wrapper">Page 1</a></div>
```

If it's not possible then how can it be done? Any soln would do.

thanks.

Comment: is the link inside the page that the iframe is pointing to or on the parent page?

Comment: parent page. Parent page is a container page with an iframe tag that loads all external pages inside parent page. External pages have links to other external pages all opening in parent page iframe.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery you can do something like this:

```
<a href="something.html" id="myLink"></a>


<script>
$(function() {
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    var iframe = $('#myIframe');
    iframe.attr("src", "newpage.html");
});
});
</script>
```

if you are use plain javascript you should find your answer here:
[change iframe source in ie using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700499/change-iframe-source-in-ie-using-javascript)