# Having an Iframe with `a` tag with some id on it, how to create a new iframe that would follow that `a` url?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We have a main web page with Iframe on it. So we have a web page loaded into Iframe. There is a link on it (`a` tag). We know its id. How to create a new Iframe on our main page that would follow that link? (link is relative to the site we put into our iframe).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700499/change-iframe-source-in-ie-using-javascript       please check this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the iframe and your web page is on the same domain, you get the a's href from the iframe's document.

```
var src =  document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('aid').getAttribute('href');
```

have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to take the full url and past it into your own iframe.

If that's not what you meant please provide code.