# Resizing iframe to fit its content

Tags: iframe, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

I have an iframe where the src is an HTML file and this iframe is put inside usercontrol:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="CName.htm" align="left" width="730" height="1100" ></iframe>
```

I need the iframe to resize according to the content so that it's height is set according to the hieght of the HTML file and I don't need to use scrolling attribute.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content

Comment: That linked answer is hopelessly out of date, see https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer for a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 19):

I've used the following jQuery code to do this:

```
$('#iframe_id').load(function () {
    $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
    $(this).width($(this).contents().width());
});
```

I don't think this will work if the iframe contents are cross-domain, though.

Comment: To do cross domain you need to use the postMessage API for this, also you need to check for window resize events and DOM mutations, so that the iFrame stays the size of the content.

Check out this lib that looks after all these things for you.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the height and width of the content inside the frame, then call a function that's on the frame's owner to set the iframe element's height and width.

Comment: This will only work if the iframe and its parent don't violate the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way! Its in jquery and its too simple. Kinda hacky..

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css({"min-height": "100", "overflow" : "hidden"});
setInterval( "$('iframe').height($('iframe').contents().find('body').height() + 20)", 1 );
```

There you go!

Cheers! :)

Comment: What's the `+20` for?