# How to dynamically resize iFrame in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe, onload

I used the solution stated on this page to resize the iFrame depending on the content:

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

And it works perfectly, except in Firefox. In Firefox, the other content is cut-off but once you keep on refreshing the page, the browser will slowly reveal the rest of the content. I saw someone replied that this is the solution to the problem:

> Use jQuery to get the body height in
>   framed.html (FF issue, body kept
>   growing): var height =
>   $(document.body).height();

However, I don't know where to put that line of code. Do I insert it somewhere within the 3 snippets of scripts on the original solution? If so, where do I put it?

Comment: Is the page inside iframe coming from same domain?

Comment: No, it's from another domain. But it's already working. I placed the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it. In case somebody else might be encountering the same problem, I used the code on the web page below which is slightly different from the link I gave above:

http://solidgone.org/Set-IFRAME-height-based-on-size-of-remotely-loaded-content

Answer (score 0):

In www.bar.net/framed.html:
Use jQuery to get the body height in framed.html (FF issue, body kept growing):

change following code

```
// What's the page height?
     var height = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

with

```
var height = $(document.body).height();
```