# Dynamically define iframe height based on window size (NOT CONTENT)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have found threads such as [How to dynamically resize iFrame in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789689/how-to-dynamically-resize-iframe-in-firefox) which talk about sizing an iframe based on the remote content; however, I have not found a way (in Firefox) to set the height of the iframe based on the window size.

Other browsers are able to use `.body.scrollHeight` but it appears that Firefox can't use that. See... http://jsfiddle.net/gjrowe/X63KR/

To see the iframe in action with the auto-sizing, view this page... http://jsfiddle.net/gjrowe/y2WCP/

It works in browsers such as Chrome but not Firefox

Comment: I know its an old thread but also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content that may be another way to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to have a cross-browser fix...

I added this javascript function...

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

I then changed...

```
var content_height=document.body.scrollHeight-100;
```

to...

```
var content_height=getDocHeight()-100;
```

You can see it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/y2WCP/9/

Comment: The answer was obtained from: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/

Comment: So this works fine. However, if I dynamically remove an element, this method continues to report the old height. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if you want to use jQuery, but with jQuery i think i fixed your problem..

```
// Header is 50px and footer is 50px; therefore, 100px is of screen height is used
// Define content_height and consider the 100px which has already been used
var content_height=document.body.scrollHeight-100;
//alert(content_height);
content_height = $(window).height() -110;
//alert(content_height);
// Set iframe height
document.getElementById('pdf_frame').style.height=content_height+"px";

// Reset iframe height after window resize
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        content_height = $(window).height()-110;
        //var content_height=document.body.scrollHeight-100;

        document.getElementById('pdf_frame').style.height=content_height+"px";
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Diabl0570/y2WCP/8/)