# Cross domain access to iframe using window.name

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I implemented a script that monitors the iframe name as I understood was OK from various sources on the net. However it seems I must have gotten something wrong - I get

*Error: Permission denied to access property 'name'

Source File: http://plungjan.name/test/testwindowname.html

Line: 16*

Please visit http://plungjan.name/test/testwindowname.html

I would prefer just to fix my script and not use jQuery or DOJO or some other framework. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

as I remember you must change iframe location to "about:blank" and after it you can access to its window.name property

Comment: But that would make a nasty blink I think - and I cannot change to about:blank UNLESS the child frame told me it needed changing!

Comment: it's only way get window.name data from iframe.
but you always can use other ways for implementing crossdomain ajax requests

Comment: I know all about that. This is a script where the iframe goes to an anchor and the parent frame needs to scroll to the top when the iframe changes

Comment: may be you can define function in parent window "scroll_to_top", and in iframe attach event to label, like this **$("#label_id").click(function(){window.parent.scroll_to_top(params) }) ** i didn't try this code, but thik it can work

Comment: Ahem nope. If I could I would not bother with the window.name rigamarole.

Answer (score 1):

Is it cross-domain communication you need here, or just the name of the window?

If the first one, take a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) - it abstracts away all the hassle with XDM across browsers ranging from IE6 to Chrome10.

Comment: Still get HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: It's up, and you should never have received a 404 anyway... http://downforeveryoneorjustme.org/easyxdm.net

Comment: Their DEMO: If you want to see it in action, [see this RPC demo!](http://easyxdm.net/Method%20not%20returning%20any%20data)

Comment: Thanks... Is there a server proxy involved somewhere there?

Comment: There are no proxies involved - everything happens in the browser between the two domains. There's a reason why Twitter, Disqus and more are using it :)

Comment: @Sean So if you take my example what exactly would I need to do?

Comment: @mplungjan First I need to know what you are actually trying to do - monitoring the name property is only the means, not the goal right?

Comment: Yes. The goal is to know when the iframe has changed so the top frame can move to top

Comment: Yes to what? It was not a yes/no question. Point is - you cannot read the name of a window who's document comes from  a different domain. But if you need cross-domain communication, then you can use easyXDM for this.

Comment: `Yes it is only the means not the goal`. That is the yes answer to your yes/no question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Has a Cross Domain solution ... but you need to have access to both the servers to implement this solution.

Comment: Possble. I do not need to resize. I need to monitor the url change