# How to store ajax return data into the browser cache

Tags: jquery, json, caching, browser

I'm returning a lot of configurations to the browser through ajax request.  I'm wanting to store the objects into the browser cache.  **NOT the html5 local storage**. I have well over 5mb worth of objects that need to be stored. Is there a way to set this data through the java script and then be able to access it later?  I haven't been able to find much if any good material on the subject.

Comment: With the proper headers, the data is automatically cached. For special cases, you might want to have a look at the [HTML5 App Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-appcache/info). Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8320121

Comment: What would the proper header look like?

Answer (score 1):

One little-known fact is that `window.name` can hold about 4MB of data. If you stringify your JSON you can stash it in there. Note, that this is not domain-safe, so any other page will have access to that data as well. You can get around this by using an Iframe in your own page, then set the window.name value of the Iframe. So, in theory you could use multiple Iframes to hold different data segments.

See:

http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/10/11/leveraging-window.name-transport-for-secure-and-efficient-cross-domain-communications.aspx

[Cross domain access to iframe using window.name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092973/cross-domain-access-to-iframe-using-window-name)

http://blog.piotrj.org/2009/04/wndowname-hack-taken-step-further-full.html