# Cross domain scripting failure in secure environment

Tags: jquery, https, cross-domain

I am using postmessage from [Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html).  I have 2 separate applications set up.  Local - local, local - dev server (windows 2003) and dev server - dev server (different ports) all work.

Our test environment is inside PCI Compliance.  One of the requirements that I thought might be an issue is that all outbound traffic is restricted.  I have opened outgoing traffic on ports 80 and 443 to the external server, but still the cross domain scripting is not working.

I am just at a complete loss as to how to get this to work.  It was working just fine in an environment where the two machines can see each other and communicate freely between each other.  Any ideas why the message is being "sent" but not received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Conroy's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content) rather than a third party library.

Answer (score 1):

As cross-domain communication should happen entirely in the browser no firewalls should be involved.

The plugin from Ben isn't the best one - you should instead go for [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) (yes, I'm the author), which is way better, much better support, much faster, and have a lot more features in general.

About the problem, it is most likely just a code error - are you for instance using the correct `origin` when sending messages`