# Resize the content of an iFrame based on the iFrames height and width

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

What i want to do is use an iFrame to embed, specifically a map, and I want to resize the map based on the values in the iFrame tag.  I have looked around and all I can find is how to auto-size the iFrame based on the content...this is opposite of what I want to do.

To Clarify, I want to adjust the size of the embedded content based on the iFrame height and width specs

One thing to note is that YouTube does this somehow but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use javascript?

If so and you've provided your iframe with a name you can access it with javascript like the following thread here: [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Comment: how do I do that from the content?