# Cross domain iframe resizing without modifying source web page

Tags: php, iframe, cross-domain, resize

I have an iframe resizing problem where I don't have access to or permission to change the source code so I cannot add any code to it.

I've found other solutions, but they only deal with when [you have control of both sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content/362564#362564)  (own site and source site)

How do I resize an iframe without modifying the source page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to get around the same-origin policy without modifying the code. Can you provide more information as to what you do have accesss to edit and/or solutions you've tried?

Comment: Right now I am trying to use PHP file_get_contents() to download the whole page to my local and put it in a html file so that I can resize the iframe, but I think it is really a bad solution. Otherwise, I don't have any ideas about how to deal with this problem