# Grails display gsp inside div

Tags: grails, render

Hey. Imagine i have two separate gsp pages with diferent css formatting (with name conflicts between two). And i want to "display" or render one page with its ows formatation inside a div in the other page. Imagining this scenario:

page1.gsp

```
...
...
<div id="here"></div>
...
...
```

page2.gsp

```
Hello there!
```

I want my final page to be:

```
    ...
    ...
    Hello there!
    ...
    ...
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: ... did you look at the g:render tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use the g:render tag and create a "fragment" page to contain your content.

then use the g:render tag to pull it in.

Refer to the documentation or tutorials for more detail on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to a question I posted a couple of days ago: 
[Can I display an inner dive with an independent stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982336/can-i-display-an-inner-div-with-an-independent-stylesheet)

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want to work for every page?  (Like a layout?)

If that is the case, use SiteMesh (built in already)

{app}/grails-app/views/layouts/mylayout.gsp

```
<html>
<head>
<g:layoutTitle default="My Application" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'layout.css')}" />
<g:layoutHead />
</head>
<body>
<div id="here"><g:layoutBody /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

{app}/grails-app/views/{somefolder}/page1.gsp

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="layout" content="mylayout" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'page1.css')}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello There!!!!
  </body>
</html>
```

If you already have that, and are just looking at breaking up you pages and keeping them DRY..

{app}/grails-app/views/{somefolder}/page1.gsp

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="layout" content="yourLayout" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'page1.css')}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="here2"><g:render template="page2" model="[foo:'bar']"/></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*** The Model property of render is optional, but works for passing data to the template to be rendered

{app}/grails-app/views/{somefolder}/_page2.gsp

*** Notice the "_" before the gsp name.  (Convention for Template pages)

```
Hello There
```

Checkout the documentation for [render and templating](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.3%20Views%20and%20Templates)