# keydown on document is not working when clicked on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, keydown

I am using

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
  alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

This function works great when the page is loaded..Now when i click on any part of the page and then when i press any key this event is not firing and alert does not come..

Why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/5cyqC/

Comment: Can you provide a (not) working example, including the relevant html code etc?

Comment: Because you are no issue, you are just losing the focus...

Comment: My guess would be you have an event handler somewhere which is preventing the event bubbling to the document for certain elements, either due to a `return false` or `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Jan — It's not about the points. If 80% of someone's questions don't get an answer good enough to accept, then that suggests a problem with the questions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5cyqC/3/   click here and then click on Server Error oe anywhere else... and then see

Comment: @Quentin If a person has four questions with upvoted answers that the asker doesn't consider good enough, I'd say that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @RaviTuvar then your issue is the keypress not propagating from the object. I'd say it's far from unexpected.

Comment: @Jan so isn't there any way when we click on object and the keyDown would get active?

Comment: @RaviTuvar There is. See (and accept) quentin's answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak Clearly I value my time more than you do with yours, so don't advise me to not warn people about wasting theirs.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for letting me know the SO take on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> jsfiddle.net/5cyqC/3 click here and then click on Server Error oe anywhere else... and then see

You are setting the focus to the content of an iframe.

This is a separate document and events do not bubble out of it into the parent document.

If you want to capture events from it, you will need to bind the event handlers to the document loaded in the frame.

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will apply.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460200/can-cross-origin-resource-sharing-headers-authorize-x-domain-iframe-access) for questions about communicating across iframes when the same origin policy blocks normal communication.

Note that there is no way to work around it from only one side as this would be a major security flaw. (For example, someone could put a banking website in a frame and then listen for keypress events in the bank's form to steal passwords.)