# How to getElementById() from HTML tag, that is rendered by embed javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having file - index.html, that has embed script.js.

Script.js - is rendering html `<a href="url.html" id="url">` tag.

I want to insert in index.html this code, that shows HREF value, that is rendered by script.js:

```
var d = document.getElementById( 'url' );
alert(d.href);
```

But this script is working only on tags, that are written index.html.

How to get the script work?

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = document.getElementById( 'url' );
alert(d.href);
</script>
```

script.js:

```
document.write("<iframe src=iframe.html></iframe>");
```

iframe.html:

```
<a href=url.html id=url>Test URL</a>
```

**--- EDITED ---**

My friend came up with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var href = $("iframe").contents().find("a").attr('href');
alert(href);
});
</script>
```

But alert() is showing - "undefined"

Comment: Can you Explain further this part: "I want to insert in index.html this code, that shows HREF value, that is rendered by script.js:"

`var d = document.getElementById( 'url' );
alert(d.href);`
"
But this script is working only on tags, that are written index.html."

Answer (score 2):

You have a frame, `document.getElementById()` won't automatically access it. Try this:

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("url");
```

In the first line, I get a reference to the frame by accessing the first `<iframe>` element of the page. There are several other methods of doing so.

Comment: I don`t know why, but this is not working for me. I made index.html like this: `var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var a = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("url");
alert(a.href);`

Comment: @Attorney What does 'not working' mean? Are there any errors in the JS dev console?

Comment: @Attorney Can you please post the full error message in your question?

Comment: frame.contentWindow is null or not an oject

Comment: @Attorney Do you host the frame source on the same domain?

Comment: with sample test yes, but with the real one - no. But the sample isn`t working for either.

Comment: @Attorney Do you run the sample from your hard drive (i.e. using the `file:///` protocol)? This could be an issue. Cross-domain iFrame access can't be done - not even using CORS, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460200/can-cross-origin-resource-sharing-headers-authorize-x-domain-iframe-access).