# Facebook iframe height

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, height

is there any way how to auto resize the iframe(canvas) to show all my content? I don't want the scrollbar. I tried every JS method and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it's quite tedious. See this answer here: [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content/362564#362564)

Comment: Thanks, but the topic is almost 3 yrs old. There must be some another solution (I would rather shoot myself in my leg than implement this code).

Comment: It still applies, cross domain scripting is a security constraint which is there for a reason.

Comment: I find [the solution!](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91458)

Comment: awesome! Good to know. You can answer your own question too : )

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
     FB.Canvas.setSize();
});
```

Wait till everything has loaded then reset the size.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works for all content height's, even when I need to decreased it:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      oauth: true
   });

      FB.Canvas.setSize({height:600});
      setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()",500);
};
```