# Height of the site within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can i find out the height of the content in the iframe?

I use `<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" />` for example. How can i display the entire height ?

Comment: Actually you can, here is the great explanation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Information about the [content of pages on other sites is off-limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).