# How to get Iframe size of current page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page with an Iframe. I am using the following code to get the size of Iframe:

```
<script language="javascript">
function sn()
{

alert('height is now '+document.getElementById("Iframemain").height)
alert('height is now '+document.getElementById("Iframemain").width)
}
</script>
<input type="button" onClick="sn()" value="Show height/width">
```

I have also another page with an Iframe but i do not know the id of the Iframe. I want to know the size the of the Iframe using javascript. How can i do it?

thanx in advance .

Thanx Rory McCrossan 
i have also tried that following code but getting udefined in alert msg.

```
<script language="javascript"> function sn() 
{

var frame = window.frames[0];
 alert(frame.width) 
 alert(frame.height)

 } 
</script>
 <input type="button" onClick="sn()" value="Show height/width"> 
</html>
```

Comment: Are the two pages using the same domain?

Comment: no they are on different domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the ID of the frame, and it is the only frame/iframe on the page you can use the following code:

```
var frame = window.frames[0];
alert('height is now ' + frame.height)
alert('width is now ' + frame.width)
```

If it is not the only frame, you'll need to change the `window.frames[index]` as required.

Comment: Too add on to your answer; if the frame contains a `name` attribute you can also use `window.frames['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Domain scripting is very difficult. Even something simple like getting the height and width is hard. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153152/350538) earlier stack overflow question for a comprehensive solution.