# pass parent url to iframe - iframe auto resize

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, autosize

I'm using a solution I found here on stackoverflow that auto sizes an iframe based on its content.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/362564/258594

My iframe is being used by several websites so I need the call to the helper file to be dynamic instead of hard coded. How can I pass the parent url to my iframe to change the following line.

```
pipe.src = 'http://www.foo.com/helper.html?height='+height+'&cacheb='+Math.random();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding the url to the iframe src

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="foo.html#http://www.ParentURL.com"></iframe>
```

Then accessed it in the iframe srouce file

```
URL = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var height = document.body.scrollHeight;
var pipe = document.getElementById('helpframe');
pipe.src = URL + '/helper.html?height='+height+'&cacheb='+Math.random();
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="foo.html"></iframe>
```

**Second Solution**

```
<iframe width="auto" height="auto" src="foo.html"></iframe>
```

> foo.html

```
<body>
<div style="width:200px;height:300px;">
<p>Your all content</p>
</div>
</body>
```