# Embed widget with auto height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed

We are trying to develop a widget that can be embedded by third parties on their sites. The height of the widget should be automatically adjusted by the embed script.

We initially thought of using an IFrame that is created by the js code. I know that it is not possible for the code in the IFrame to set the height of the IFrame after loading due to browser security issues.

Does anyone have another idea how to solve this? We thought of using the way disqus.com does it with their widgets. You can see an example here:http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/the-webs-original-tv-show-ramp-up-continues-on-hulu-and-youtube.php. Look at how they load the html and place it inside the main page rather than use an IFrame.

Looking forward to some help!

Thanks,

Assaf

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/resize-iframe-based-on-content/