# Track only iframe history

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page which contains an iframe and I want to track the history of the iframe only. 
I tried to use the history object like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkFrameHistory() {
            alert(window.frames["test2"].history.length);
        }

        function checkThisHistory() {
            alert(history.length);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <iframe name="test2" src="test2.html"></iframe>

        <div>
            <input type="button" onclick="checkFrameHistory()" value="Frame history"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="checkThisHistory()" value="This history"/>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkMyHistory() {
            alert(history.length);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        Test2
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="checkMyHistory()" value="My history"/>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

but it actually gave me the history including the parent window.

For instance, I went to another site in the main window and came back to my iframe test site. Both `window.frames["test2"].history.length` and `history.length` still gave me the same count by increasing the length by 2.

Did I do it wrong? Is there a way to track only the iframe history?

Comment: What is in the test2.html page?

Comment: Just added the test2.html but it is just a simple test page. Thanks!

Comment: This [INFO](http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/iframe-and-browser-history) can help with additional information.

Comment: Is this behaviour consistent in all browsers?

Comment: I am testing this in chrome, safari and firefox. And I tried to access it using contentWindow of the iframe but still the same.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome manages history on window base; not on separate frames. This behaviour is probably the cause of your problem.

Dont know if its default behaviour for all browsers btw.

Edit: You have to maintain your navigationhistory server side. Keeping an array on the mainwindow, as stated in another answer, doesnt work when you also navigate with the parent window.

Comment: Valid point explaining the source of the problem, but it lacks an explanation of how to solve his problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy way to do this, provided of course that the iframe content is the same domain.

From the parent you bind to the `beforeUnload` or the `load` event of the iframe's window object. In the event's callback handler you simply do something along the lines of `locations.push(getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.location.href)` where locations is of course a previously defined array in the parent scope.

Comment: Can I use the same for different domain url? If not, why its not possible?

Answer (score 3):

use this to access the history of iframe

```
document.getElementById("test2").contentWindow.history.length
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely you will be able to access any objects associated with the frame because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Have you tried setting the domains to be equal on the page itself and the iframe? e.g.

```
//somewhere on your page in a script tag
document.domain = "your-top-level-domain.com";
```

this should signal to the browser that the pages trust each other and should be given access to their internal state

Comment: um... currently those html pages are localhost and should be on same domain already... it seems like i am able to access the history in the iframe like: `window.frames["test2"].history`... at least i don't get any error... it is just that the frame's history object seems to be including the original page history instead of just referring to the iframe history only...

Comment: oh i see my mistake. Right, try changing your code to access the iframe as such `window.frames["test2"].contentWindow.history`. The `contentWindow` is the important part

Answer (score 0):

If the frame contains **contentWindow**, you can use **frame.contentWindow.history**.

But not all browsers support this property. If not, the frame's location should be stored in some variables.
Bind event handler on your frame onload event like below(using jquery)

```
var frameHistory = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var frame = window.frames["test2"];
    $.bind(frame, "onload", function(){ //store location when frame loads
        frameHistory.push(frame.window.location.href);
    }
});
```

And in your button click event handler:

```
alert(frameHistory.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ITS POSSIBLE** to beat SOP as long as you have access to both domains. You can use a helper IFRAME to pass onchange events from the BODY.

This post should be extremely helpful:
[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)