# How to make use of history.back within iframe to not affect parent window url?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-history

If the parent URL changes since the iframe is loaded and `history.back(-1)` is triggered from within the iframe, then the parent URL will go back.

This can be reproduced here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/Ljrwx6d9/19/show/light/

Can this be prevented?

Comment: weird.... didn't expect that behavior. Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745564/track-only-iframe-history

Comment: Did you find solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: I'm looking for that as well... any luck? I've tried comparing parent history length to frame length and "if" it, but it's very unstable.

Comment: Unfortunately i did never find a solution to this.