# Cross-domain iframe jquery selector

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to make cross-domain iframe content inside local jquery dialog. When I was developing it in same application everything was fine. When I tryed to test it on another application with another url i get error:

```js
Error: Permission denied to access property ...
```

I know, there are problems with Security Policy, but I need to make selections inside frame. 
 
Let me show you what I do:

 `foo/plugin.js:`

```
    var frameDOM;
    function frameLoaded() {
        for (var i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
            if (window.frames[i].name == "frame-name-here") {
                frameDOM = window.frames[i].document;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        var frame = "<iframe src='http://bar:222/Home/frame' id='frame-content' name='frame-name-here' onload='frameLoaded()' />";

    $("#dialog-form").dialog({ autoOpen: true, height: 450, width: 500, modal: true, resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Deliver": function () { //Some long code here
                        }
                }
                create: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).append(frame);
                }
            });
```

And after frame is loaded I can easily access to content inside frame:

```js
 $("#frame-input", frameDOM).val();
```

With cross-domain I lost such possibility. Is there other way to control selectors insode frame, taken from another domain?

 
P.S. I don't need to [Resize frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content) and that solution didn't helped. I'm looking for alternate way, since this one isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unless you can grab the HTML via PHP or some other scripting language (using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP possibly) which would then pass it back to your JavaScript application from the same domain, this is not possible. Please refer to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).