# Incorrect height of div returned by JS functions. Why?

Tags: javascript

I try to get size of main div on page, to make iframe change its height to content, but `document.getElementById("divId").offsetHeight` (also try `innerHeight`) return wrong value. It always returns 247, but in fact page looks like it cut on 75%. I have an idea that page didn't load fully, so I put resize code in the footer of the page, but it still return 247.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     console.log(document.getElementById("resizeDiv").offsetHeight);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: console.log(document.getElementById("resizeDiv").height); giving?

Comment: Do it in `$(window).load(` instead of in `$(document).ready(`

Comment: What does jQuery `.height()` give? Also, your HTML/CSS is probably crucial to answering the question.

Comment: Can you setup a demo on http://jsfiddle.net? Probably the values returned are correct, but you are expecting something different. It depends on how your elements are defined in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found other decision, I just get height of body and it works good:

```
var height = Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight, 
document.body.clientHeight, 
document.body.offsetHeight, 
document.documentElement.scrollHeight, 
document.documentElement.offsetHeight, 
document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

Answer (score 7):

Add setTimeout to wait screen load and get correct height.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("resizeDiv").offsetHeight
}, 300);
```

Comment: Works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to load your function after the DOM is loaded.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // do something
});
```

See [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     console.log($("#resizeDiv").height());    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using jQuery, why not try:

```
$(function() {
    $('#resizeDiv').height();
});
```

It sounds like you may be trying to resize an iFrame based on the content inside it. If you are trying to do that, this question has already been answered here:

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Comment: what`s the difference between raw height method of JS and wrap of Jquery? :-) I suppose none, cause Jquery calls raw JS method. I checked, it gives the same value.

Comment: Looking at the jQuery source, $(target).height() is an alias for $(target).css('height');

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("resizeDiv").offsetHeight`, it gives the actual height of the element in pixels. The value includes the height of any padding and borders.

`document.getElementById("resizeDiv").style.height` is similar to .height, except you're asking for the height part of the style attribute.

`document.getElementById("resizeDiv").height` is only valid if the element has a height attribute, such as an IMG tag:

```
<img src="..." width="200" height="300">
```

It's a shorthand for `document.getElementById("resizeDiv").getAttribute("height")`.

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event on the `window` object triggers when the whole page is loaded including styles, images and other resources. We can use this to get the correct height:

```
window.onload = function () {
    element.offsetHeight;
}
```

Comment: Fails to return different values for body height when browser window is changed then refreshed: document.body.offsetHeight stays the same.