# Cross Domain Child window DOM reference

Tags: javascript

I pop up a 3rd party website in a child window. Will I be able to reference its DOM objects from the parent window? How can I do this?

Comment: Only if the 3rd party website has the same domain, protocol and port.

Comment: Do you use `window.open()`?

Comment: @David Cross-document messaging works across domains, i.e. the same origin policy does not apply. But then, only strings can be transferred, so I guess I'm off topic.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yes, but sending messages does not mean "access to the DOM". You won't be able to transport a DOM object (reference).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer:

You can not violate SOP period.

The loophole is using a parent.parent scheme where at least to request for the properties is being made through the same origin:

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Answer (score 0):

```
 childWindow = window.open ("http://www.yourDomain.com","mywindow");

  childWindow.onload = function () {
     childDocument = childWindow.document;
     // now you can do things like, childDocument.getElementById("someElement"); and other DOM manipulation.

    };
```