# jQuery iframe.load status

Tags: jquery, iframe, load, http-headers

Is there a way I can find whether there's an http error status inside an iframe?

I'm loading the iframe with a dynamically built url and am removing a loading gif on load.

```
$("#reportFrame").load(function () {
        kendo.ui.progress($("#report-container"), false)
        $('#btnReportRefresh').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('k-state-disabled');
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    });
```

All of this is ok, but in the event of an error inside this page, I would like to show my own error text rather than what gets shown inside the iframe.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**
Note that the iframe will always be loaded on a different domain.

Comment: Is the iframe content an arbitrary page, or something you could modify?

Comment: I can modify it yes. Ideally I wouldn't bit I'd prefer having this than nothing.

Note that the iframe will always be loaded on a different domain.

Comment: If the frame is loaded from a different domain, you can't access the contents from the parent (whether or not the contents are an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question, but here's an update.

I went down a route similar to this:

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible in the way you're hoping, but what about an interval that checks the contents? Something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#reportFrame body").html() === "This is an error page") {
    // Do Something
  } else {
    //Do something else
}, 500)
```