# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'ResizeIframe'

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, resize

I'm following the tutorial (over 300 votes!) to resize an iframe according to the height of the content on [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content).

My problem is that I"m getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'ResizeIframe' in my helper.html.

Wondering if anyone has followed the stackoverflow answer before and encountered this problem too.

My helper.html:

```
<html> 
<h1>Helper</h1>
<!-- Testing small change. -->
<!-- 
This page is on the same domain as the parent, so can
communicate with it to order the iframe window resizing
to fit the content 
--> 
  <body onload="parentIframeResize()"> 
<script> 
// Tell the parent iframe what height the iframe needs to be
function parentIframeResize()
{
var height = getParam('height');
// This works as our parent's parent is on our domain..
parent.parent.resizeIframe(height);
}
// Helper function, parse param from request string
function getParam( name )
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null )
      return "";
    else
      return results[1];
  }
</script>
```

My javascript file (on the domain that the iframe is embedded within):

```
function resizeIframe(height)
{
// "+60" is a general rule of thumb to allow for differences in
// IE & and FF height reporting, can be adjusted as required..
if (document.getElementById('embedded-iframe')) {
document.getElementById('embedded-iframe').height = parseInt(height,10)+60;
}
}
```

Again, most of the code comes from this stackoverflow post: [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content).

Comment: Should it really be parent.parent? You have an iframe in an iframe/frame?

Comment: change like this `resizeIframe = function(height)`

Comment: @epascarello That's correct. The first iframe is embedded on the page, and it has a "helper" iframe whose height adjusts its height.

Comment: i didn't follow the tutorial you referenced, but my function does essentially the same thing and i'm getting the same error about 1/3 of the time the page loads.