# Alert its current HEIGHT inside IFRAME itself?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, height

*First of all*
*I have no interest in resizing the* `iframe`.

---

I'm trying to make the Website inside an `iframe` to alert its document height.

Simply I have this pages:

**www.PARENT.com**

```
<body>
  <iframe src="http://www.CHILD.com" />
</body>
```

**www.CHILD.com**
- index.html
- contactus.html

```
  <!-- ** FOOTER SCRIPT ** -->
  <script>
    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                           html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

    alert( height ); //NOW TELLING MY HEIGHT!
  </script>
```

As mentioned above, in `www.CHILD.com`, there are a few pages with different heights, like:

- www.CHILD.com/index.html -- 450px
- www.CHILD.com/contactus.html -- 1000px

And I'm using the script above at *footer* section of *both* pages.

But then whenever I run the `www.PARENT.com` page, I *always* get:

Alert:

```
450
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing an iframe based on content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Comment: Who said i want to RESIZE the IFRAME??? (Totally NOT interested in your thing to buy!) Just asking how to make IFRAME to ALERT its current height.