# Youtube Subscribe Embed is cutting off the corners of my image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embed, styling

When I embed my Youtube channel using the official embed code on Google Devs https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button it is cutting off the corners of my image resulting in white corners, since my website has a black background it's not looking good at all.

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="full" data-theme="dark" data-count="default"></div>
```

https://imahappy.eu/
[- Issue I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuS7f.png)

is it possible to style the
`.yt-thumb {background: #f1f1f1;}` as removing this from the Element Inspector fixes the issue.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly edit the iFrame itself due to [CORS restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225590/i-would-like-to-manipulate-the-html-inside-an-iframe-using-jquery).
I see a workaround here though. Youtube gives your the possibility to generate a button without the channel picture. So you can take the button and use the image separately.

A sidenote: I noticed you have an eu domain and you also address eu citizen. Directly embedding the Youtube subscribe button is against GDPR regulations in the EU. Your site also doesn't have a proper impress with all your contact details.