# How can I dynamically change the height of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dynamic, height

How can I dynamically change the height of an iFrame containing a Pardot form?  I have a Pardot form that is placed on a page in my site via iFrame.  I have tried a number of ways to dynamically resize the iFrame depending on the size of the form.  When a user submits the form, much of the data is stored and the forms becomes shorter the next time the page is viewed.  The iFrame code is as follows:

```
<iframe 
    src="http://go.pardot.com/..." 
    width="100%" 
    type="text/html" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allowTransparency="true" 
    style="border: 0" scrolling="no" 
    id="iframe" 
    onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this);">

</iframe>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
function resizeIframe(obj) 
{
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've a third-party page loaded on the `iframe`. If so, you [can't access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) the document within `iframe`. If it's not a third-party content, just remove the `height` attribute from the `iframe` tag. Where's Java?

Comment: Most browsers won't let javascript access the contents of an iframe from a different domain.  However, you'll have much better luck with onreadystatechange than you will with onload.

Comment: @Dave What you mean with "most browsers"? Any of them won't. If they would, that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: I was striving for brevity.

Comment: Java and Javascript have very little in common. Your code is Javascript, not Java.

Comment: @Teemu - To be pedantic, one could take an open source browser and compile it to allow such actions :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ebookContainer">
<iframe class="ebookFrame" src="http://iFrameURL.com" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ebookContainer {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ebookFrame {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good thread about that here:
[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)
And iframe resize lib here https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer
(I haven't yet check that plugin, but hope it could help you)

Articles above contain many usefull links.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS to assign a class, called mine frame-pardot and don't set the height.

```
.frame-pardot {
    min-height:200px;
    max-height:800px;
    width:100%;
}

<iframe src="????????????" class="frame-pardot" scrolling="no">
```

Then you can also adjust for mobile devices using @media