# Determining if iframe has been loaded

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe

I'm trying to figure out the size of an iframe's content so I can resize the iframe element to compass its content.

How do I find out if the iFrame has been loaded and I can reliably measure it's content dimensions.

Note: `onload` event won't do because the iframe can be loaded by the time `onload` is bound. Also, I'd like a vanilla JS solution not jQuery.

Comment: Unless you have origin control (like on same server/domain), then I do not think this is possible.

Comment: I do have origin control.

Comment: oh great. Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

1- The iframe should have an ID:

> ```
> <iframe    
>   id="slideshow_frame"    
>   src="frame.html"   
>   frameborder="0"    
>   width="100%"    
>   marginheight="0"    
>   marginwidth="0"
>   scrolling="no">
>  </iframe>
> ```

2- The page loaded into the iframe should contain all the html into an “easy retrievable” container (a div with an ID is perfect!):

> ```
> <div id="content">
>     <div style="background: red; width: 400px; height: 120px"></div>
>     <div style="background: green; width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
>     <div style="background: yellow; width: 400px; height: 60px"></div>
> </div>
> ```

3- You can trigger this function wherever you want:

> ```
> function resizeIframe(iframeID) {       
>    var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(iframeID);
>    var container = document.getElementById('content');
>    iframe.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px';            
> }
> ```

Source:

[Adapting iframe height to its content with 2 lines of javascript](http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/06/12/adapting-iframe-height-to-its-content-with-2-lines-of-javascript/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.