# Get iframe content height in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe

can anyone help me to do this code works on Google Chrome?
It work's perfectly on IE.

Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function calcIframeSize() {
      var altura = $("body", $("#frameExtraFields").contents()).height();
      $("#frameExtraFields").height(altura);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#frameExtraFields").ready( function() {
        calcIframeSize();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="frame.html" width="80%" height="600" id="frameExtraFields"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content?rq=1)

Comment: Your problem comes from `$("#frameExtraFields").ready` which does not mean that the document inside the iframe is loaded.

Comment: I've tried to change the ready event to load event, but didn't work. Only in Chrome and Firefox doesn't work. In IE it works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your iframe loads a `src` on the same domain, the following should do it :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#frameExtraFields').load(function() {
            $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
        });
    });
</script>

<iframe src="/user/login/" width="80%" height="auto" id="frameExtraFields"></iframe>
```

Notice I removed the fixed height you set on the `iframe` element and setted it to `auto` instead.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu7vua60/3/)

Comment: I had already tested it before, but it did not work.

`    <script>
      function calcIframeSize() {
        var altura = $("body", $("#frameExtraFields").contents()).height();
        $("#frameExtraFields").height(altura);
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#frameExtraFields").load( function() {
          calcIframeSize();
        });
      });
    </script>`

Answer (score 1):

> Solution:

I do use the below code for all browser which *specifically* look for **chrome**:

The **`.offsetHeight`** returns same value in chrome compared with **`.scrollHeight`** in rest of the browsers.

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

if (document.getElementById) {
    newheight = isChrome 
    ? document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight 
    : document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}
```

> Complete function to resize the iframe height:

```
function autoResize(id) //id = iframe-id
{
    var newheight = 500;
    var newwidth;

    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

    if (document.getElementById) {
        newheight = isChrome ? document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight : document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

        newheightVisible = newheight + 30; //Don't ask me why this, i am also wondering but it works
    }

    if (newheight != lastheight) {
        jQuery("#" + id).css('height', newheightVisible);
        lastheight = newheightVisible;
    }
}
```