# Height issue in HTML rendering as an Iframe

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage

http://hashgurus.com/q.aspx?q=%23ReplaceASongTitleWithSausage which displays the contents properly in a rectanguar box. The height is adjusted to the contents of the div tag.

The same set of code works weirdly while put in a IFrame as shown: The height of the contents are cut abrubtly. I tried adjusting the height but to no avail.

http://hashgurus.com/feed/master.html

any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add iframe height

```
height="100%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `scrolling="no"` in your iframe's inline styles, and the height it's defaulting to is shorter than the iframe content (you could add a style like `iframe {height: 500px}`)

Comment: I donot want an height to be set. I want the height to be automatically adjusted to the length of the contents. Is that possible? I donot want a scrolling bar

Comment: Ok, then you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content