# how to make a frame's height the same as the content's?

Tags: javascript, iframe

i create a frame like this:

```
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.src = 'https://apis.google.com/u/0/wm/4/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&first_party_property=YOUTUBE&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D' + location.href.match(/v=(.+?)([#&]|$)/)[1];
```

but I would want the frame to have the same height the source has, so all is visible, instead of setting a static height and getting scrollbars.
maybe I did it wrong, but `overflow = visible` didn't seem to work.

Comment: Might want to check out this http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/height/

Comment: or may have a look to similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content

Comment: im not sure those would work.
i need the frame to resize itself every time, not just on "onload". i cant create helper sites, and its not on the same domain.
i basically just need to do the same youtube does with the comment frame. it resizes every time more comments are loaded. how did they do it?