# How to adjust iframe size dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a iframe and should adjust it's size dynamically based on content in it.

I used like this 
but it's not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for lots of good answers and discussion: [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Long story short, if the iFrame is a cross-domain request you're going to have a bad time. Built-in browser security measures make the content within an iFrame difficult to access (on purpose).

Comment: The answer in that question is very out of date, their are a few JS solutions that are much easier to use these days. Check out https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: Yeah, that's a great script. However, it still requires a js file to be on both the contained page and the parent page (which could be problematic in some cases).