# Get height tag html5 <embed> for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the height from an external page that is inside an embed tag with jQuery.

I also need to resize the embed tag when the content inside changes in height. I tried using the following code but it doesn't seem to work. What would be the best approach for this case?

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <embed src="www.example.com" height="100%">
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#test').height()
$('embed').height()
```

Comment: Let's do some testing first: `console.log($('#test').text());`, does this work for you? How about `console.log($('embed').text());` ?

Comment: You mean *element height* instead of *tag height*, don't you?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Can we see the HTML here? It's not clear what attribute you're trying to find exactly.

Comment: @AGE , I tried using it but it didn't work. The result was an empty string.

Comment: @ThiagoAleixo it's just what you should expect unless you actually expect it to be empty. The element should contain some kind of text right? So that means your selector is not actually accessing the element,. You need to find the correct selector to use and try again, I would like to help but honestly without any HTML it's hard to guess. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing an iframe based on content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Comment: The same issues with doing this in an iframe apply to embed tags.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I'm with the problem yet.

My Html code is something like this:

<html>
 <body>
  <embed src="www.example.com" height="100%">
 </body>
</html>

Analysing the html rendered, this embed has a #document, and I think that for this #document I won't get a height of the embed

Height="100%" does't work too, only width="100%".

Comment: heights defined to percent are relative to parents, not to childrens. Try defining `html, body { height: 100% }` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours I solved my problem with this:

[cross domain](http://michilehr.de/resize-iframe-by-its-content-cross-domain/)

This saved my integration from my application in asp.net with WordPress.

Thanks for everybody that tried help me.