# Easy XDM - IFrame Navigation Breaks Socket

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, easyxdm

I'm using EasyXDM to handle cross-domain communication so that the parent knows both the size of the child and the location of the child.  I've got the sizing working.  The issue is when I navigate while inside the iframe I want to push the location back up to the parent.

The issue is that when I change page that the socket fails to get created again, giving me **VM87 Core.js:324 Uncaught Error: url is undefined or empty**.

Anyone else run into this?

Parent(consumer):

```
<script language="javascript">
    (function () {
    // CTOR has side effect of creating globals for socket
        var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
            remote: "@(Model.Url)" + document.location.hash,
            container: $("#pluginFrame")[0],
            onMessage: function (message, origin) {
                var messageAsObject = JSON.parse(message);

                if (messageAsObject.height) {
                    $("#pluginFrame iframe").height(messageAsObject.height);
                }

                if (messageAsObject.path) {
                    document.location.hash = messageAsObject.path;
                }
            },
            onReady: function() {
                console.log("Shell Socket Ready");
                $("#pluginFrame iframe").width("100%");
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Child(producer) Razor Layout

```
<script language="javascript">
    (function () {
        debugger;
        var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
            onReady: function () {
                console.log("eBox Ready");

                socket.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                    height: $(".body-content").outerHeight(),
                    path: document.location.pathname
                }));
            }
        });

        $("body-content")
            .on("change",
                function () {
                    socket.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                        height: $(".body-content").outerHeight()
                    }));
                });

        $(document.location.pathname)
            .on("change",
                function () {
                    socket.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                        path: document.location.pathname
                    }));
                });

        socket.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
            path: document.location.pathname
        }));
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I've seen there's no possible way to do what I'm after.  It seems that the only solution for the problems I was ultimately trying to solve, pushing routing into the location hash of the parent, is to use the double iframe approach mentioned here.

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)