# iframe responsive: if the size content of the window iframe changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Help me find a solution for the responsive iframe window.
For example: if the size content of the window iframe changes, iframe resize automatically in parent window.

***Note***: in iframe window dynamically content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Comment: My situation another. Inside frame have javascript which generates content. And I find solution, I need: detected height change.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from Avi:

// *HTML*

```
<div class="myIframe"> 
   <iframe> </iframe> 
</div>
```

// *CSS*

```
.myIframe {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 65.25%;
     padding-top: 30px;
     height: 0;
     overflow: auto; 
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; //<<--- THIS IS THE KEY 
     border: solid black 1px;
} 
.myIframe iframe {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```