# Changing iFrame Height Accordingly To Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, that checks the iFrame content width every 0.1 seconds. This code works, but I don't think it is best practice.

Here is my code

```
function iframeLoaded() {
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById('appframe');
    if (iFrameID) 
    {
        iFrameID.height = ''; 
        if (iFrameID.height != iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px') 
        {
            iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    }
}

setTimeout(iframeLoaded, 100);
```

and the HTML

```
<iframe src='https://google.com' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' id='appframe' onload='iframeLoaded()'></iframe>
```

Would the best solution be to check if the iFrame height has changed every 0.1 seconds, and only then adapt the size of iframe height if a change has been noticed.

As now, the code is adapting the height, even if they detect no change in iFrame height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Comment: `that checks the iFrame content width every 0.1 seconds` ... from your code, I can say you're checking only once after 0.1s, not every `0.1s` What are you actually trying to acomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a event listener:

`var iframeWindow = document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow; $(iframeWindow).on('resize', function(){
 //... 
});`