# I cannot seem to get my iframe to resize to the page I'm referring it to

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I can't get the IFrame I have to properly resize to the contents of the page it's displaying. I'm on the latest version of chrome, and yes, I know others have made answers on how to do it, but no matter what I try nothing works. It either zooms in on the page (best try I've had yet tbh) or it just stays the same as if I've never changed anything.
I don't know S*** about javascript, so please help me out

I've already tried a ton of things, you name it, I've probably tried it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){

        var iFrames = $('iframe');

        function iResize() {

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
              iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

               iFrames.load(function(){
                   setTimeout(iResize, 0);
               });

               for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
               }

            } else {
               iFrames.load(function() { 
                   this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
               });
            }

        });

</script>
<iframe src="https://www.thundergaming.net/forums" class="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Right now that just zooms in on the page, like it was resized, but the actual window stayed the same. I need the site and the actual IFrame to resize to the IFrames contents, making everything seemless as if you were actually on that page and not looking at an iframe.

Comment: There is an error in Firefox, it says `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object` Maybe your server is restricting to access document which is why you cannot get the document size that you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content?rq=1