# Hide the Iframe scrollbars but still can scroll

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar

Actually, I know that this question has been a lot even just in stackoverflow, but still, the answers I found does not work for me - lots of them are asked long ago. But however, I'm trying to put an iframe inside a web page, and it's from the same origin. The problem is, every time I scroll, these annoying scrollbars came out. I've tried to make changes like adding `overflow: hidden` (which makes it worse - it disables scrolling!), `scrolling="no"` (same as overflow, disables scrolling), and more. Is there a simple way that I can remove the scrollbar on the iframe but still can scroll it? CSS are better, but if it can be done in JavaScript at someways, it's also OK. Thanks a lot!!

Update: My code:

the parent page: (things in {%%} and {{}} are jinja templates, I use them to render the template)

```html
<!-- 
  @Author: Sam Zhang
  @Date:   2020-04-10 20:05:53
  @Last Modified by:   Sam Zhang
  @Last Modified time: 2020-05-06 17:01:45
-->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ keyword }}{% endblock %}

{% block top %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Guangdu <small class="text-light">Baidu</small></a>
        <form method="post" class="container-fluid" style="max-width: 60%; margin-left: 0"
                action="{{ url_for('baidu.index') }}">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="query" value="{{ keyword }}" id="search" autocomplete="off" type="search">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Guangdu</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a onclick="changeTheme()" href="" class="text-white" title="Change theme"><i class="fa fa-adjust"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="iframe-wrap">
    <iframe id="iframe iframe-real" onload="$(this).fadeIn(500); show()" seamless="seamless" src="{{ url_for('baidu.search_s', q=keyword, page=cur) }}" class="iframe"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="load-container">
        <div class="spinner-grow text-primary" role="status" id="load">
            <span class="sr-only" id="load-sr">Loading</span>
        </div>
   </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function hide() {
            $("#iframe").hide();
            $("#load-container").fadeIn(500);
            $("#load").fadeIn(500);
            $("#load-sr").fadeIn(500);
        }
        function show() {
            $("#load-container").fadeOut(500);
            $("#load").fadeOut(500);
            $("#load-sr").fadeOut(500);
        }
        window.onload = hide();
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And my web page in the iframe:

```html
<!-- 
  @Author: Sam Zhang
  @Date:   2020-04-10 20:05:53
  @Last Modified by:   Sam Zhang
  @Last Modified time: 2020-05-06 17:26:20
-->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ keyword }}{% endblock %}

{% block top %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}id="body" style="overflow:auto;height:100%" onload="document.getElementById('body').style.width=document.body.offsetWidth+20+'px'"{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <style>

    </style>
    <script>
        function change(pn) {
            this.parent.location.href = "{{ url_for('baidu.search') }}?q={{ keyword }}&page=" + pn;
        }
    </script>
    {% if results %}
    {% for result in results %}
        {% if result.title and result.link %}
            <div class="container">
                {% if result.domain %}
                    <p class="text-success">
                        {{ result.domain }}
                        {% if result.path %}
                            &rsaquo;
                            {% for loc in result.path %}
                                {% if loop.index != result.path | length %}
                                    {{ loc }}
                                    &rsaquo;
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ loc }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </p>
                {% endif %}
                <h5 id="{{ loop.index }}h5"><a href="{{ result.link }}" target="_blank">{{ result.title }}</a></h5>
                {% if result.time %}<p class="d-inline text-muted">{{ result.time }} &middot; </p>{% endif %}<p class="d-inline text-secondary text-wrap" id="{{ loop.index }}">{% if result.des %}{{ result.des }}{% else %}No description{% endif %}</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <div class="container">
            <p>Keyword {{ keyword }} has np search results</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                {% if cur != 0 and cur != 10 %}
                    {% set url = "javascript:change(pn='" + (cur - 1) | string + "')" %}
                {% else %}
                    {% set url = '#' %}
                {% endif %}
                <li class="page-item{% if cur == 0 %} disabled{% endif %}">
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ url }}" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% if pages | length <= 10 %}
                    {% for i in pages %}
                        <li class="page-item{% if i == cur %} active{% endif %}"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:change(pn='{{ i }}')">{{ i + 1 }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if cur < pages | length %}
                    {% set url = "javascript:change(pn='" + (cur + 1) | string + "')" %}
                {% else %}
                    {% set url = '#' %}
                {% endif %}
                <li class="page-item{% if cur == pages | length - 1 or cur == 9 %} disabled{% endif %}"{% if cur == 9 %} data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"{% endif %}>
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ url }}" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hacky solution, but this will hide the scrollbars by making the frame bigger than the container.

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer iframe {
  width: 520px;
  height: 170px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   
  <iframe src="/"></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't really know how long it the main content in the iframe is... Is there a way to get that?

Comment: You can choose any height and width you need and can even use percentages (ex. `width:100%` and `width:120%`). Finding the size of the iframe's content is a separate question which has answers in many threads (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content?rq=1). It may be more difficult if the src is on a different domain.